# Multiple filed for one attribut

Tags: symfony, twig

i don't know how create tow inputs for one attribut in the data base using tiwg and i want in my twig file to be just like this [here is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWVas.png)

i tried to add to time the same input in the my form builder but it isn't working

```
{{ form_label(form.moisAnne) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="nom-l-kiity"> mois </label>
        {{ form_widget(form.moisAnne) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.moisAnne) }}

    {{ form_label(form.moisAnne) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="nom-l-kiity"> mois </label>
        {{ form_widget(form.moisAnne) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.moisAnne) }}
here mois == month 
and annee == year
```

Comment: "it isn't working" isn't particularly helpful for debugging. do you get errors? what do you get? do you know about `{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal.html.twig' %}` and the like?

Comment: i don't get any errors its just i can't split a textType in towµ
i try to add in my builders tow time same attribute but it isn't showing in my twig file even i added tow time widget i don't know how to splite it

Comment: oh, you mean split in two? yeah you probably have to make some data transformation in your form and make it actually two form fields.

Comment: how i can do that in my builders ?

Comment: can you show your form builder and the underlying object you try to change?

Comment: here you can see my builder and twig file and what i have tried https://gist.github.com/Bakhshi-Faisal/e3b9bcde5f6276636a47ffa4aa761165 
mois == month 
annee == year
i'm living in france so sorry for my english

Comment: still missing the `AppBundle\Entity\FicheFrais`

Comment: i updated my gist now you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I can tell, you have multiple options:

#### use a data transformer

this is definitely the clean solution and to be preferred above the others. Essentially you turn parts of the data you get into an array/object (moisAnne) and use it to fill multiple fields.

longer and probably better description: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html (it's actually in addition to the following instruction)

1. First you create a new form type `MoisAnneType` that has two fields, mois and anne.
2. Then you create a data transformer, that turns your moisAnne into an array `['mois' => $mois, 'anne' => $anne]` (and of course also the reversal).
3. use the new form type in your original form for the moisAnne field
4. in your template you probably don't have to explicitly render it, but you also can use `form.moisAnne.mois` and `form.moisAnne.anne`.

#### expand the entity (the cheap data transformer)

add getter and setter to your `AppBundle\Entity\FicheFrais` that use arrays to communicate:

```
public function getExpandedMoisAnne() {
    $mois = /** your code **/
    $anne = /** your code **/
    return ['mois' => $mois, 'anne' => $anne]; 
}
public function setExpandedMoisAnne(array $moisAnne) {
    $this->moisAnne = $moisAnne['mois'].$moisAnne['anne']; // or whatever
}
```

then, in your form builder you can just use

```
->add('mois', null, [
     'property_path' => 'expandedMoisAnne[mois]'
])
->add('anne', null, [
     'property_path' => 'expandedMoisAnne[anne]'
])
```

#### event listeners

I believe this option to be quite dirty, anyhow, I'm certain that one could use `FormEvent`s to add unmapped fields that are not part of the original object and make data transformations in the event listeners/handlers. I would highly advise against this.